# data accessing from Rally

Tags: rally

I am trying to access rally data with API key,username and password but getting **"HTTP ERROR 401 Problem accessing Reason: Full authentication is required to access this resource Powered by Jetty"** issue.
I am using Node Version 10.18,
Can anyone help me in this.